# Time for a particle to reach the centre of a potential on a straight path

Tags: homework-and-exercises, classical-mechanics, potential

I'm working on a problem in classical mechanics. We have a particle moving in a potential $V=\frac{-a}{r^n}$ where $a$ and $n$ are given constants.

Now we let go of the particle at the position $r(t=0)=R$ at $t=0$ where the starting velocity $v(t=0)=0$ aswell.

The time it takes to reach the centre of the potential "in a straight path" is proportional to $R^{\eta}$. The task is to find $\eta$. Honestly I have no idea how to start. Theres also a hint, that its not necessary to calculate integrals explicitely to solve the problem, which doesnt help me at all.

Hope someone can help! Greetings

Comment: Hint: Kepler's 3rd law for an elliptic path with eccentricity 1

Comment: Hi and welcome to the Physics SE! Please note that we don't answer homework or worked example type questions. Please see [this page in the site help](https://physics.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) for more on what topics you can ask about here.

Comment: Work out the acceleration

Comment: You need not calculate an integral *explicitly* , but you can still *inspect its scaling properties* ! What about the integral of *dr/v* from R to 0 where v is easily furnished by conservation of energy?

Answer (score 0):

You need not calculate the integral explicitly, but you must consider its scaling properties. The integral is of course the integral of *dt*, where
$$
dt= -\frac{dr}{v(r)}~ ,
$$
*v(r)* being the increasing magnitude of the velocity, starting at $v(R)=0$ and ending up divergent, $v(0)=\infty$.

From conservation of energy, you know 
$$
-a\frac{1}{R^n}= \frac{mv^2}{2}-a\frac{1}{r^n} \qquad \Longrightarrow \\
v(r)= \sqrt{ 2(a/m) \left (\frac{1}{r^n}-\frac{1}{R^n}\right )} ~,
$$
so that the time elapsed is
$$
\int_0^R dr \frac{1}{\sqrt{ 2(a/m) \left (\frac{1}{r^n}-\frac{1}{R^n}\right )}}  .
$$
Can you now scale a power of *R* out of this?

Comment: Did not accept the answer?

Comment: Mass typo fixed. You may delete your comment.